# How convert webm to mp4?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, webcam, mp4, webm

I am unable to convert a webm file created through webcam recording to mp4.

I am using below command.

```
ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -i  uploads/2586913190845018.webm -r 24 uploads/abc.mp4 2>&1
```

The output of above command is

```
Array
(
    [0] => FFmpeg version 0.6.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2010 the FFmpeg developers
    [1] =>   built on Jan 29 2012 17:52:15 with gcc 4.4.5 20110214 (Red Hat 4.4.5-6)
    [2] =>   configuration: --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib64 --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --incdir=/usr/include --disable-avisynth --extra-cflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -fPIC' --enable-avfilter --enable-avfilter-lavf --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdirac --enable-libfaac --enable-libfaad --enable-libfaadbin --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --enable-shared --enable-swscale --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-x11grab
    [3] =>   libavutil     50.15. 1 / 50.15. 1
    [4] =>   libavcodec    52.72. 2 / 52.72. 2
    [5] =>   libavformat   52.64. 2 / 52.64. 2
    [6] =>   libavdevice   52. 2. 0 / 52. 2. 0
    [7] =>   libavfilter    1.19. 0 /  1.19. 0
    [8] =>   libswscale     0.11. 0 /  0.11. 0
    [9] =>   libpostproc   51. 2. 0 / 51. 2. 0
    [10] => [matroska @ 0x14ce690]max_analyze_duration reached
    [11] => [matroska @ 0x14ce690]Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
    [12] => Input #0, matroska, from 'uploads/2586913190845018.webm':
    [13] =>   Metadata:
    [14] =>     doctype         : webm
    [15] =>   Duration: 00:00:00.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
    [16] =>     Stream #0.0(eng): Video: 0x0000, 640x480, PAR 1:1 DAR 4:3, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn, 30 tbc
    [17] =>     Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, mono, s16
    [18] => swScaler: Unknown format is not supported as input pixel format
    [19] => Cannot get resampling context
)
```

Above command works if I upload webm file download from youtube or any other online source, it works.

Comment: Try with `-analyzeduration 10M` before `-i`

Comment: I tried following command but still getting same error.

ffmpeg -fflags +genpts -analyzeduration 10M -i  uploads/2586913190845018.webm -r 24 uploads/abc.mp4 2>&1

Comment: Your version is very old. Update to current version.

Comment: thanks after updating it's working fine